# Calculate difference from previous item in a group with (single) LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate difference from previous item, when the data needs to be grouped.

I have data like this

```
City      Area  Date        Citizens
New York    1   2010.11.20  5
New York    1   2010.11.21  8
New York    1   2010.11.22  12
New York    1   2010.11.23  17
New York    1   2010.11.24  23
New York    1   2010.11.25  29

Chicago 1   2010.11.20  5
Chicago 1   2010.11.21  10
Chicago 1   2010.11.22  15
Chicago 1   2010.11.23  20
Chicago 1   2010.11.24  25
Chicago 1   2010.11.25  30

New York    2   2010.11.20  6
New York    2   2010.11.21  7
New York    2   2010.11.22  9
New York    2   2010.11.23  7
New York    2   2010.11.24  10
New York    2   2010.11.25  15

Chicago 2   2010.11.20  5
Chicago 2   2010.11.21  15
Chicago 2   2010.11.22  25
Chicago 2   2010.11.23  20
Chicago 2   2010.11.24  25
Chicago 2   2010.11.25  30
```

and I need to add a column "Increase" for each are for each city, which would be calculated by subtracting previous Citizens count from current.

```
The expected result is like this

City    Area    Date    Citizens    Increase
New York    1   2010.11.20  5   5
New York    1   2010.11.21  8   3
New York    1   2010.11.22  12  4
New York    1   2010.11.23  17  5
New York    1   2010.11.24  23  6
New York    1   2010.11.25  29  7

Chicago 1   2010.11.20  5   5
Chicago 1   2010.11.21  10  5
Chicago 1   2010.11.22  15  5
Chicago 1   2010.11.23  20  5
Chicago 1   2010.11.24  25  5
Chicago 1   2010.11.25  30  5

New York    2   2010.11.20  6   6
New York    2   2010.11.21  7   1
New York    2   2010.11.22  9   2
New York    2   2010.11.23  7   -2
New York    2   2010.11.24  10  3
New York    2   2010.11.25  15  5

Chicago 2   2010.11.20  5   5
Chicago 2   2010.11.21  15  10
Chicago 2   2010.11.22  25  10
Chicago 2   2010.11.23  20  -5
Chicago 2   2010.11.24  25  5
Chicago 2   2010.11.25  30  5
```

I wonder if this can be done with a single linq query, avoiding 
"foreach (c in cities)
    foreach (a in area)
       ...."

The problem is how to calculate line "7" where simply diff to previous record would be -24, when is should be 5.

Here's a sample code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class MyObject
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string City { get;set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public int DiffToPrev { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            var list = new List<MyObject>
              {
                new MyObject {ID= 1, City = "New York",Date = DateTime.Now,          Value = 5},
                new MyObject {ID= 1, City = "New York",Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),Value = 8},
                new MyObject {ID= 1, City = "New York",Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2),Value = 12},
                new MyObject {ID= 1, City = "New York",Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3),Value = 17},
                new MyObject {ID= 1, City = "New York",Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4),Value = 23},
                new MyObject {ID= 1, City = "New York",Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5),Value = 29},

                new MyObject {ID= 1, City = "Chicago",Date = DateTime.Now,           Value = 5},
                new MyObject {ID= 1, City = "Chicago",Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),Value = 10},
                new MyObject {ID= 1, City = "Chicago",Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2),Value = 15},
                new MyObject {ID= 1, City = "Chicago",Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3),Value = 20},
                new MyObject {ID= 1, City = "Chicago",Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4),Value = 25},
                new MyObject {ID= 1, City = "Chicago",Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5),Value = 30},

                new MyObject {ID= 2, City = "New York",Date = DateTime.Now,          Value = 6},
                new MyObject {ID= 2, City = "New York",Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),Value = 7},
                new MyObject {ID= 2, City = "New York",Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2),Value = 9},
                new MyObject {ID= 2, City = "New York",Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3),Value = 7},
                new MyObject {ID= 2, City = "New York",Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4),Value = 10},
                new MyObject {ID= 2, City = "New York",Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5),Value = 15},

                new MyObject {ID= 2, City = "Chicago",Date = DateTime.Now,           Value = 5},
                new MyObject {ID= 2, City = "Chicago",Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),Value = 15},
                new MyObject {ID= 2, City = "Chicago",Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2),Value = 25},
                new MyObject {ID= 2, City = "Chicago",Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3),Value = 20},
                new MyObject {ID= 2, City = "Chicago",Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4),Value = 25},
                new MyObject {ID= 2, City = "Chicago",Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5),Value = 30},               
            };

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do in this way:

```
var newList = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.City, x.ID })
.Select
(
    x =>
    {
        var subList = x.OrderBy(y => y.Date).ToList();
        return subList.Select((y, idx) => new MyObject
        {
            ID = y.ID,
            City = y.City,
            Date = y.Date,
            Value = y.Value,
            DiffToPrev = (idx == 0) ? y.Value : y.Value - subList.ElementAt(idx-1).Value 
        });
    }
)
.SelectMany(x => x)
.ToList();
```

---

Anyway, I think in this case a foreach statement is clearer (and not longer), e.g.:

```
List<MyObject> newList = new List<MyObject>();
foreach (var grp in list.GroupBy(x => new { x.City, x.ID }))
{
    MyObject prev = null;
    foreach (var obj in grp.OrderBy(y => y.Date))
    {
        newList.Add(new MyObject
        {
            ID = obj.ID,
            City = obj.City,
            Date = obj.Date,
            Value = obj.Value,
            DiffToPrev = (prev == null) ? obj.Value : obj.Value - prev.Value
        });
        prev = obj;
    }
}
```

**P.S.**
obviously (depending on your needs) in the foreach code you can set the `DiffToPrev` directly on the existing object (`obj`) instead of creating a new one, making optional the creation of `newList`.

---

**Results:**

```
ID: 1,City: New York,Date: 21/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 5,Diff: 5
ID: 1,City: New York,Date: 22/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 8,Diff: 3
ID: 1,City: New York,Date: 23/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 12,Diff: 4
ID: 1,City: New York,Date: 24/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 17,Diff: 5
ID: 1,City: New York,Date: 25/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 23,Diff: 6
ID: 1,City: New York,Date: 26/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 29,Diff: 6
ID: 1,City: Chicago,Date: 21/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 5,Diff: 5
ID: 1,City: Chicago,Date: 22/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 10,Diff: 5
ID: 1,City: Chicago,Date: 23/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 15,Diff: 5
ID: 1,City: Chicago,Date: 24/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 20,Diff: 5
ID: 1,City: Chicago,Date: 25/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 25,Diff: 5
ID: 1,City: Chicago,Date: 26/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 30,Diff: 5
ID: 2,City: New York,Date: 21/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 6,Diff: 6
ID: 2,City: New York,Date: 22/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 7,Diff: 1
ID: 2,City: New York,Date: 23/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 9,Diff: 2
ID: 2,City: New York,Date: 24/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 7,Diff: -2
ID: 2,City: New York,Date: 25/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 10,Diff: 3
ID: 2,City: New York,Date: 26/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 15,Diff: 5
ID: 2,City: Chicago,Date: 21/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 5,Diff: 5
ID: 2,City: Chicago,Date: 22/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 15,Diff: 10
ID: 2,City: Chicago,Date: 23/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 25,Diff: 10
ID: 2,City: Chicago,Date: 24/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 20,Diff: -5
ID: 2,City: Chicago,Date: 25/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 25,Diff: 5
ID: 2,City: Chicago,Date: 26/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 30,Diff: 5
ID: 1,City: New York,Date: 21/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 5,Diff: 5
ID: 1,City: New York,Date: 22/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 8,Diff: 3
ID: 1,City: New York,Date: 23/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 12,Diff: 4
ID: 1,City: New York,Date: 24/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 17,Diff: 5
ID: 1,City: New York,Date: 25/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 23,Diff: 6
ID: 1,City: New York,Date: 26/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 29,Diff: 6
ID: 1,City: Chicago,Date: 21/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 5,Diff: 5
ID: 1,City: Chicago,Date: 22/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 10,Diff: 5
ID: 1,City: Chicago,Date: 23/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 15,Diff: 5
ID: 1,City: Chicago,Date: 24/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 20,Diff: 5
ID: 1,City: Chicago,Date: 25/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 25,Diff: 5
ID: 1,City: Chicago,Date: 26/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 30,Diff: 5
ID: 2,City: New York,Date: 21/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 6,Diff: 6
ID: 2,City: New York,Date: 22/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 7,Diff: 1
ID: 2,City: New York,Date: 23/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 9,Diff: 2
ID: 2,City: New York,Date: 24/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 7,Diff: -2
ID: 2,City: New York,Date: 25/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 10,Diff: 3
ID: 2,City: New York,Date: 26/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 15,Diff: 5
ID: 2,City: Chicago,Date: 21/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 5,Diff: 5
ID: 2,City: Chicago,Date: 22/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 15,Diff: 10
ID: 2,City: Chicago,Date: 23/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 25,Diff: 10
ID: 2,City: Chicago,Date: 24/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 20,Diff: -5
ID: 2,City: Chicago,Date: 25/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 25,Diff: 5
ID: 2,City: Chicago,Date: 26/11/2010 12:52:40,Value: 30,Diff: 5
```

Comment: Edited, I calculated 0 to the first entry instead of the current value ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
list.OrderBy (l => l.Date)
    .GroupBy (l => new { l.ID, l.City })
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(g => g.Aggregate (0, (acc, m)  => { m.DiffToPrev = m.Value - acc; return m.Value; }));
```

Here I order by date in case they are out of date order, then group by ID and City.  Take that into a List, and then for each group, use an Aggregate function to set the difference from the previous value in the group.

You can see the results in [ideone](http://ideone.com/AyTUo):

```
ID: 1, City: New York, Date: 11/21/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 5, DiffToPrev: 5
ID: 1, City: New York, Date: 11/22/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 8, DiffToPrev: 3
ID: 1, City: New York, Date: 11/23/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 12, DiffToPrev: 4
ID: 1, City: New York, Date: 11/24/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 17, DiffToPrev: 5
ID: 1, City: New York, Date: 11/25/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 23, DiffToPrev: 6
ID: 1, City: New York, Date: 11/26/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 29, DiffToPrev: 6
ID: 1, City: Chicago, Date: 11/21/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 5, DiffToPrev: 5
ID: 1, City: Chicago, Date: 11/22/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 10, DiffToPrev: 5
ID: 1, City: Chicago, Date: 11/23/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 15, DiffToPrev: 5
ID: 1, City: Chicago, Date: 11/24/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 20, DiffToPrev: 5
ID: 1, City: Chicago, Date: 11/25/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 25, DiffToPrev: 5
ID: 1, City: Chicago, Date: 11/26/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 30, DiffToPrev: 5
ID: 2, City: New York, Date: 11/21/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 6, DiffToPrev: 6
ID: 2, City: New York, Date: 11/22/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 7, DiffToPrev: 1
ID: 2, City: New York, Date: 11/23/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 9, DiffToPrev: 2
ID: 2, City: New York, Date: 11/24/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 7, DiffToPrev: -2
ID: 2, City: New York, Date: 11/25/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 10, DiffToPrev: 3
ID: 2, City: New York, Date: 11/26/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 15, DiffToPrev: 5
ID: 2, City: Chicago, Date: 11/21/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 5, DiffToPrev: 5
ID: 2, City: Chicago, Date: 11/22/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 15, DiffToPrev: 10
ID: 2, City: Chicago, Date: 11/23/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 25, DiffToPrev: 10
ID: 2, City: Chicago, Date: 11/24/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 20, DiffToPrev: -5
ID: 2, City: Chicago, Date: 11/25/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 25, DiffToPrev: 5
ID: 2, City: Chicago, Date: 11/26/2010 9:01:30 AM, Value: 30, DiffToPrev: 5
```

Comment: Even if your code it's perfectly working, actually your LINQ `Aggregate` usage it's a bit hacky.  
In fact what are you doing there is nothing more than a foreach with an initial status, but more obfuscated. IMHO in these cases (i.e. LINQ with side effects) it's preferable to use loops (or `List.ForEach`/ `ForEach` Extension) because is clearer what it's intended to do.

Comment: In my opinion there's one more argument to be taken into account. The DATA is actually stored in the SQL server and translated into objects vis ORM (such like MS Entity or Devexpress XPO). In this case moving as many operations to SQL server is a priority (meaning that sql server would do the grouping, sorting and counting if possible)

Answer (score 2):

Solution using [Reactive extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx):

```
var zero = EnumerableEx.Return(new MyObject { Value = 0 });
var result = list
    .GroupBy(o => new { o.City, o.ID })
    .SelectMany(g => g
        .Zip(zero.Concat(g), (o1, o2) =>
        new { O = o1, Diff = o1.Value - o2.Value }));
```

You need to reference `System.Interactive`.

Another version reusing your `MyObject`:

```
var result = list
    .GroupBy(o => new { o.City, o.ID })
    .SelectMany(g => g
        .Zip(zero.Concat(g), (o1, o2) =>
            new MyObject {
                ID = o1.ID, City = o1.City, Date = o1.Date, Value = o1.Value, DiffToPrev = o1.Value - o2.Value
            }));
```

Comment: @Martynas This *is* LINQ, but these new methods are available only since **.NET 4.0**. To use them in previous versions of .NET, you can download libraries separately.