# how do access previous item in list using linQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have:

```
List<int> A  = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6};

List<int> m=new List<int>();
for(int i=1;i<A.count;i++)
{
int j=A[i]+A[i-1];
m.add(j);
}
```

how can I do this same operation using LinQ?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your question, but why not just use a `for` loop? Changing the above to LINQ probably won't gain you anything.

Comment: I like to know how do like this using linQ so only

Comment: You don't capitalise the Q in LINQ, all the letters are part of the acronym, not just the Q :)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Well, a straightforward translation would be:

```
var m = Enumerable.Range(1, A.Count - 1)
                  .Select(i => A[i] + A[i - 1])
                  .ToList();
```

But also consider:

```
var m = A.Skip(1)
         .Zip(A, (curr, prev) => curr + prev)
         .ToList();
```

Or using Jon Skeet's extension [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683105/calculate-difference-from-previous-item-with-linq/3683217#3683217):

```
var m = A.SelectWithPrevious((prev, curr) => prev + curr)
         .ToList();
```

But as Jason Evans points out in a comment, this doesn't help all that much with readability or brevity, considering your existing code is perfectly understandable (and short) and you want to materialize *all* of the results into a list anyway.

There's nothing really wrong with:

```
var sumsOfConsecutives = new List<int>();

for(int i = 1; i < A.Count; i++)
   sumsOfConsecutives.Add(A[i] + A[i - 1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the .Zip() solution. It's clean, and you only read the array 2x.

Comment: @TNT `Zip` (or any overload which causes `IEnumerable<T> source` to be enumerated twice would be inappropriate for many uses (e.g. when the `IEnumerable<T>` cannot be iterated more than once, e.g. one operating over a one-way `StreamReader`).

Answer (score 17):

Ok so getting the next item in the list you can use:

```
A.SkipWhile(x => x != value).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

So to get the previous item use:

```
var B = A.ToList();
B.Reverse();
B.SkipWhile(x => x != value).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: might also try
A.TakeWhile(x => x != value).LastOrDefault()

Answer (score 4):

How about something like

```
var l = A.Skip(1).Select((x, index) => x + A[index]).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Some of the other answers assume that the elements of A are always going to be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.  If those values ever change then the solution would break, such as the values changing to 2, 3, 6, 7, 10.

Here's my solution that will work with any values of A.

```
List<int> m = A.Skip(1).Select((element, index) => element + A.ElementAt(index)).ToList();
```

It is worth noting that sticking with a loop would probably be better than hacking together a Linq solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

In case you only need the end value, you can Aggregate it, ie. you need previous value, but dont need each individual value to a new list.

```
int last = 0;
var r = m.Aggregate(last, (acc, it) => (last += it), (acc) => (last));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to implement your own `Buffer` operator and use that to make a simple LINQ statement.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Buffer<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int size)
{
    var buffer = new List<T>();
    foreach (var t in source)
    {
        buffer.Add(t);
        if (buffer.Count() == size)
        {
            yield return buffer.AsEnumerable();
            buffer = buffer.Skip(1).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

That allows this code:

```
List<int> B = A.Buffer(2).Select(x => x.Sum()).ToList();
```