# Dictionary linq select previous

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

How to get a previous element in select(foreach) some like this `dic[index -1].Key`

```
new Dictionary<int, double>();

dic.Select(x => x.Value*(x.Equals(dic.FirstOrDefault()) ? x.Key : //x.Key - dic[index -1].Key//)).Sum()
```

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered.  `FirstOrDefault()` will not work correctly here.

Comment: Can you expand your answer and tell us why you need to do this? It'll help us help you

Comment: Dictionaries don't have an order.  If you used an `OrderedDictionary` then a `foreach` may be cleaner since you'll need to keep track of the "last" key.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do access previous item in list using linQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460106/how-do-access-previous-item-in-list-using-linq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Select` method provides an index as a second parameter.

```
dic.Select((x, index) => dict[index])
```

If you want to select an element at previous index you can use `ElementAt`

```
dic.Select((x, index) => dic.ElementAt(index).Key)
```

Comment: And how would you apply that to the problem?  `dict[index]` will NOT select the "nth" item; it will return the value where `index` is the key.

Comment: but how access to key because dict[index].(value only) - my dictionary contain for ex: 23,10.00; 150,56.7; and i need to getting exactly key

Comment: @AleksP I've updated the answer. In fact I think it would be easier done with just an ordinary `for` loop

Comment: @AleksP You still need to deal with the fact that a `Dictionary` isn't necessarily ordered by its key.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an `OrderedDictionary` then it may be faster to use a straight `foreach`:

```
double sum = 0.0;
int prev = 0;
foreach(var kvp in dic)
{
    sum += kvp.Value * (kvp.Key - prev);
    prev = kvp.Key;
}
```

In any case, I would first come up with something that *works* and then refactor it if you can make it *better*.  And "better" may not be using Linq; a convoluted Linq query that's hard to understand and debug is worse than a clean, efficient loop in most cases.