# C#, How to get differences in a list or an array

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking for ways to calculate difference two items in array or list using LINQ.
I think ExtensionMethod is another good solution, but I wolder how to do it by LINQ.
Please Help Me.

```
var items = new List<int> { 238, 348, 274, 490, 459, 349 };

Console.WriteLine($"{items[0]} - 0 = {items[0]}"); 

for (int i = 1; i < items.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{items[i]} - {items[i-1]} = {items[i] - items[i-1]}");
}

result:
238 - 0 = 238
348 - 238 = 110
274 - 348 = -74
490 - 274 = 216
459 - 490 = -31
349 - 459 = -110
```

I expect like this:

```
//this code does not work!!!
items.ForEach((prev, next) => Console.WriteLine($"{next} - {prev} = {next - prev}"));
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can write your extension method : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Comment: Thank you for your comment.But I want to know it by LINQ.

Comment: You could use `Aggregate()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netcore-3.1 or this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460106/how-do-access-previous-item-in-list-using-linq

Comment: @JaeChulKim are the values unique?

Comment: your first line 238 - 0 has no sense, or no logic..your program cant give the result you display

Comment: @JaeChulKim The first line of the result with the code shown is *not* "238 - 0 = 238".

Comment: No,  it is just a list.

Comment: @ Frenchy, @Andrew Morton     Please ignore first result. I just copy & paste result of my program,  My mistake, sorry.

Comment: @Christoph Lütjen Thank you for your advice. I tried and solve this program by your help.
 `int last = 0;
            var r = items.Aggregate(last, (prev,next) => {
                Console.WriteLine($"{next} - {prev} = {next - prev}");
                return next;
            }, next => last); `

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you want that logic, but one way to do it in LINQ is using `Zip` like below:

```
var items = new List<int> { 238, 348, 274, 490, 459, 349 };
var results = items.Prepend(0)
     .Zip(items, 
            (itemFromPrepended, itemFromOriginal) => 
            $"{itemFromOriginal} - {itemFromPrepended} = {itemFromOriginal - itemFromPrepended}");
```

`items.Prepend(0)` returns you a list with `0` in front (.i.e. `{ 0, 238, 348, 274, 490, 459, 349 }`)

`Zip` will take these 2 lists and apply the lambda provided to one element from each list. The lambda I provide there just formats it as a string, you can transform it anyway you want. I also make the lambda variable name a bit more verbose so you know what are those variables

Comment: The OP clarified that they don't want the "238-0" line, so just `string.Join("\r\n", items.Zip(items.Skip(1), (a, b) => $"{b} - {a} = {b - a}"))` will do for an answer using `Zip`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks. I missed the comments. Yeah your comment should solve it in that case

Answer (score 0):

Sure this can be done by (ab?)using the LINQ `Aggregate` method:

```
var differences = items.Aggregate(new { Previous = 0, List = new List<int>()}, (aggregate, current) =>
{
    aggregate.List.Add(current - aggregate.Previous);
    return new { Previous = current, aggregate.List};
}).List;
```

This creates a list of the differences you want. If you just want the `Console.WriteLine` you can just aggregate with an int value and output the differences directly.

But I hope this is just for knowledge, in practice imo in this case just stick to the for loop, much cleaner.

Another option if you want to use the LINQ `ForEach` and do your `Console.WriteLine` you could do something like this:

```
var previous = 0;
items.ForEach(item =>
{
    if (previous.HasValue)
        Console.WriteLine($"{item} - {previous} = {item - previous}");
    previous = item;
});
```

But once again nothing wrong with using the `for` loop. I really feel people go blind in their desire to use LINQ for everything.

EDIT: I see you asked to ignore the first "weird" output, basically skipping the first value, this is how that would look for both cases:

```
var differences = items.Aggregate(new { Previous = (int?)null, List = new List<int>()}, (aggregate, current) =>
{
    if (aggregate.Previous.HasValue)
        aggregate.List.Add(current - aggregate.Previous.Value);
    return new { Previous = (int?)current, aggregate.List};
}).List;

int? previous = null;
items.ForEach(item =>
{
    if (previous.HasValue)
        Console.WriteLine($"{item} - {previous} = {item - previous}");
    previous = item;
});
```

Comment: Using Aggregate() makes imho sense IF you pass in an accumulator function instead of writing the code inline. E.g. `items.Aggregate(MyAccumulators.DiffWithLast)`. Compared to extension functions you keep your intellisense clean.

Answer (score 0):

@Christoph Lütjen Thank you for your advice. I tried and solved it.

```
int last = 0;
items.Aggregate(last, (prev,next) => {
    Console.WriteLine($"{next} - {prev} = {next - prev}");
    return next; 
}, next => last); 

result:
238 - 0 = 238
348 - 238 = 110
274 - 348 = -74
490 - 274 = 216
459 - 490 = -31
349 - 459 = -110
```

@AndrewMorton Thank you too.

```
var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, items.Zip(items.Skip(1), 
    (a, b) => $"{b} - {a} = {b - a}"));
Console.WriteLine(result);

//result
348 - 238 = 110
274 - 348 = -74
490 - 274 = 216
459 - 490 = -31
349 - 459 = -110
```