# Get previous record to current one using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

If I have a list of items, and say the "id" is unique, but not necessarily sequential, is there a way to find the previous entity in say either a List or an IEnumerable?

So I may have a list of people, and they each have an id and they are sorted in an order I am not aware of.  All I get is the list and the id of the person.

Now I need to get the previous person to the id that was provided to me.

Is there a nice LINQ way to do this or do I simply find the record and get the previous one in a ForEach?

**edit**
I just found this, is this the best approach?

[Calculate difference from previous item with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683105/calculate-difference-from-previous-item-with-linq/3683217#3683217)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you need this

```
 items.TakeWhile(x => x.id != id).LastOrDefault();
```

- `Enumerable.TakeWhile` Method returns elements from a sequence as long as a specified condition is true, and then skips the remaining elements.
- We take the last or `default` from it.

Comment: This assumes that the items are in order, which, according to the question, they aren't.

Comment: Actually this works because I use items.TakeWhile(x => x.id != id).LastOrDefault(); and this then selects the previous record

Comment: Sweet. (Except change it to the form given by griegs above.) @AntP No it doesn't. Maybe you misinterpreted the question.

Comment: I think OP meant that they aren't **sorted** or that the set is not **continuous**, so you can't stop at the item that has one less ID than "current". This solution holds.

Comment: Hmmm, seems I have misunderstood the question, but "I need to get the previous person to the id that was provided to me," is a little ambiguous.

Comment: it didn't but not because your solution was bad i think.  i think it was to do with the list i was being given.  so +1 and correct answer because i think it is technically right.  thanks.