# Looking for a equivalent LINQ query for a Matlab matrix operation that uses previous values of the matrix

Tags: c#, linq

I want to simplify the generation of a List in C# using LINQ. My goal is to populate the new List with operations using values of another List.
I'm willing to use 3rd party libraries, like Deedle or MathNet, if they can reproduce similar performance to my current solution.

A equivalent way to achieve my goal in Matlab would be using simple matrix operations and a dot operation as shown in the following code:
`dailyRetList = (dailyCloseList(2:end) - dailyCloseList(1:end-1))./dailyCloseList(1:end-1)`

Which creates a new array iterating over `dailyCloseList` and for each element it subtracts `dailyCloseList[i-1]` from `dailyCloseList[i]`, then divide the result by `dailyCloseList[i-1]` and finally push the value to the newly created array.

My current solution to tackle the problem is:

```
var dailyCloseList = new List<double>{11.8d, 11.7d, 13d, 12.6d, 15d};

var dailyRetList = new List<double>();
for (var i = 1; i < dailyCloseList.Count; i++)
{
     dailyRetList.Add((dailyCloseList[i] - dailyCloseList[i-1])/dailyCloseList[i-1]);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you provide your question with more details about your expected result, because is not clear what `dailyRetList = (dailyCloseList(2:end) - dailyCloseList(1:end-1))./dailyCloseList(1:end-1)` does.

Comment: Your current solution seems fine. Is there something wrong with it, or are you just looking to achieve the same result in less code?

Comment: @Ben Yeah, my solutions works but I'm just starting in C# and LINQ so I just wanna check if there is a way to write less code.

Comment: I'm not sure. You could try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227794/get-previous-record-to-current-one-using-linq but I suspect what you're currently doing is actually simply.

Comment: Why do you want to write less code?

Comment: Just looking for options. Was my "laziness" that made me discover LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in Linq:

```
var m = Enumerable.Range(1, dailyCloseList.Count - 1)
                .Select(i => (dailyCloseList[i] - dailyCloseList[i - 1])/ dailyCloseList[i - 1])
                .ToList();
```

It always helps to check for `DivideByZero` exception.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `Zip`:

```
var change = dailyCloseList.Zip(dailyCloseList.Skip(1))
                           .Select((x,y) => (y - x)/x)
                           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most Linq-way is this

```
var dailyRetList = dailyCloseList
    .ConsecutivePairs((a, b) => (b - a) / a)
    .ToList();
```

Sure, you have to define the `ConsecutivePairs` function (once somewhere). But unlike the Guaravsa solution, this works on `IEnumerable`, so does not need direct index access. But it all comes at a price. Your original simple loop is about 3x faster that any of the solutions using enumerations (btw you should preallocate the List at the beginning for best performance).

And the function implemenatiton, just for completeness:

```
public static IEnumerable<Q> ConsecutivePairs<T, Q>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, T, Q> selector)
{
    using(var en = sequence.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!en.MoveNext()) { yield break; }
        T prev = en.Current;
        while (en.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return selector(prev, en.Current);
            prev = en.Current;
        }
    }
}
```