# Replace sequence of duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to replace every sequential duplicate using linq? I tried using groups with no success. Basically, I need to get the following results:

```
string[] arr = new [] { "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a" }; // input
string[] res = new [] { "a", "R", "R", "b", "R", "R", "R", "c", "R", "R", "a", "R" }; // output
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Select` method has an overload that takes the index, you can make use of it to check previous item:

```
res = arr.Select((x, idx) => idx != 0 && arr[idx - 1] == x ? "R" : x).ToArray();
```

Comment: This code won't compile because `res` is `string[]`, not `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: @tukaef Don't be that picky a simple call to `.ToArray` will convert it back to `string[]`. This is a fine answer

Comment: Agreed, `.ToArray()` will convert `IEnumerable<string>` to `string[]`

Comment: This code doesn't compile. `CS0173 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'char' and 'string'`

Comment: @Enigmativity You are likely trying to access an index of a string instead of the array (so `someString[4]`) which gives a char.

Comment: @EpicKip - No, the OP had `'R'` instead of `"R"`. He's edited the question. Check the change log.

Comment: @Enigmativity As far as I can tell he had neither `"` nor `'` in the original code

Answer (score -1):

You could use John Skeets Extension which he stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683105/calculate-difference-from-previous-item-with-linq/3683217#3683217).

```
  public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectWithPrevious<TSource, TResult>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
     Func<TSource, TSource, TResult> projection)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
        {
             yield break;
        }
        TSource previous = iterator.Current;
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return projection(previous, iterator.Current);
            previous = iterator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
var out  = arr.SelectWithPrevious((prev, curr) => prev==curr? R:curr));
```

Comment: Did you test this before posting?

Answer (score -2):

This works fine:

```
string[] arr = new [] { "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a" }; // input

string [] res = arr.StartWith("_").Zip(arr, (a0, a1) => a0 == a1 ? "R" : a1).ToArray();
```

Comment: I would love to know why this got a down-vote. It's better in some ways to the accepted answer - this works with any fixed enumerable, not just arrays.

Comment: @tukaef - Ah, `StartWith` is from Microsoft's Interactive Extensions.